# CKeditor5 Custom Plugin Text / Element Selection and apply styles

Tags: ckeditor5

I am making a custom plugin, I want to be able to select certain text, and apply styles to that selected text. if a block element, I'd like to add a custom style to that also. here is part of my code:

```js
class StyleManager {
  constructor(editor) {
    this.editor = editor
  }

  setStyle (styleName, value) {
    this.editor.model.change(writer => {
      const selection = this.editor.model.document.selection

      if (selection.rangeCount) {
        const firstRange = selection.getFirstRange()

        for (const item of firstRange.getItems()) {
          writer.setAttribute(styleName, value, item)
        }
      }
    })
  }

  setElementStyle (writer, element, property, value) {
    const currentStyles = element.getAttribute('customStyle') || {}
    currentStyles[property] = value
    writer.setAttribute('customStyle', currentStyles, element)
  }

  setTextStyle (writer, range, property, value) {
    if (range.isCollapsed) {
      return
    }
    const text = Array.from(range.getItems()).find(item => item.is('text'))
    const styledElement = writer.createElement('span', {
      customStyle: {
        [property]: value
      }
    })
    writer.wrap(range, styledElement)
  }
}

export default StyleManager
```

I'm not being able to set the styles using this. any help would be appreciated. I'll include my plugin.js. I am using Quasar modals to achieve this, why I'm listening to window.events...
Here is my plugin.js

```js
// CustomStylePlugin.js
import Plugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/plugin';
import ButtonView from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/src/button/buttonview';
import StyleManager from './StyleManager';

class CustomStylePlugin extends Plugin {
  static get pluginName() {
    return 'customStyle';
  }

  init () {
    const editor = this.editor
    this.styleManager = new StyleManager(editor)

    editor.ui.componentFactory.add('customStyle', locale => {
      const button = new ButtonView(locale)
      button.set({
        label: 'Manage Styles',
        withText: true,
      })
      button.on('execute', () => {
        const selection = editor.model.document.selection
        const styles = this.getStyleOfSelection(selection)
        const event = new CustomEvent('openStyleManagerModal', {
          detail: styles
        })
        window.dispatchEvent(event)
      })

      return button
    })

    // Listen for the 'updateStyles' event
    window.addEventListener('updateStyles', this.updateStyles.bind(this))

    // Add downcast conversion
    editor.conversion.for('downcast').add(dispatcher => {
      dispatcher.on('attribute:customStyle', (evt, data, conversionApi) => {
        const {
          item
        } = data
        if (!item.is('element')) {
          return
        }

        const viewWriter = conversionApi.writer
        const viewElement = conversionApi.mapper.toViewElement(item)
        const styles = item.getAttribute('customStyle') || {}
        for (const property in styles) {
          viewWriter.setStyle(property, styles[property], viewElement)
        }
      })
    })

    // Add upcast conversion
    editor.conversion.for('upcast').elementToElement({
      view: {
        name: true,
        styles: true
      },
      model: (viewElement, modelWriter) => {
        const styles = {}
        for (const [property, value] of viewElement.getStyles()) {
          styles[property] = value
        }
        return modelWriter.createElement(viewElement.name, {
          customStyle: styles
        })
      },
    })
  }

  getStyleOfSelection (selection) {
    const firstRange = selection.getFirstRange()
    const item = firstRange.start.nodeAfter
    return item ? item.getAttribute('customStyle') : {}
  }

  updateStyles (evt) {
    const styles = evt.detail
    const editor = this.editor
    const selection = editor.model.document.selection
    console.log('selection = ', selection)
    editor.model.change(writer => {
      if (selection.isCollapsed) {
        return
      }
      const range = selection.getFirstRange()
      const item = range.start.nodeAfter
      if (!item) {
        return
      }

      if (item.is('element')) {
        console.log('item is ', item)
        this.styleManager.setStyle(item, styles.property, styles.value)
      } else {
        console.log('item is ', item)
        this.styleManager.setStyle(range, styles.property, styles.value)
      }
    })
  }
}

export default CustomStylePlugin
```